# Xcode Signing Ad Hoc vs Release

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have 2 provisioning profiles, one for `Development` and one for `AdHoc`. I understand `Signing(Ad Hoc)` should choose the `Development profile`. Should I select `AdHoc profile` for `Signing(Ad Hoc)` section? And for `Signing(Release)`, does it mean for `App Store profile`?

Comment: what Xcode version are you using. The newer versions manage all of these for you. After doing a Product -> Archive, you will see an option to distribute the app. Here when you select the relevant distribution type, you will see an option to "Automatically manage signing".

Comment: @Raunak I am using Xcode 10.2.1. I don't trust this "Automatically manage signing". I prefer set it manually. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 2):

- Developer - allows running on devices listed in the signing profile,
  with debug permissions
- Ad-hoc - allows running on devices listed in
  the signing profile
- App store - allows running on any device, but
  only after it is re-signed by Apple
- Enterprise - allows running on
  any devices owned by your organization (requires Enterprise developer
  account)

Comment: Yes, I understand those. If you look into the General panel in XCode. You will find `Signing (Ad Hoc)` and `Signing (Release)` these two sections. I am confused about these two. Does it mean the `Ad Hoc` should use the AdHoc profile and Release should use the AppStore profile?